# Trying to run PostFIX mail server. But mail sending in not working

Tags: php, postfix

I was trying to setup postfix MTA to use the mail() function in PHP.
Using MAMP 4.1 the free version on Mac OSX sierra PHP version 7.1.0 
I am not interested to use MAMP PRO and third party libraries like swiftMailer, as I want to stick to the basics.

As of now, I have updated done the following:

1. Created a file called sasl_passwd with my credentials as:

   ```
   [smtp.gmail.com]:587 myemail@gmail.com:mypassword
   ```
2. Used the following commands then:

   ```
   sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
   sudo chgrp postfix sasl_passwd*
   sudo chmod 0640 sasl_passwd*
   sudo postmap -q [smtp.gmail.com]:587 sasl_passwd
   ```
3. Opened up the main.cf at /etc/postfix/ and added the following lines at the end

   ```
   #Gmail SMTP
   relayhost=smtp.gmail.com:587
   # Enable SASL authentication in the Postfix SMTP client.
   smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
   smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
   smtp_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
   smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter=plain
   # Enable Transport Layer Security (TLS), i.e. SSL.
   smtp_use_tls=yes
   smtp_tls_security_level=encrypt
   tls_random_source=dev:/dev/urandom
   ```
4. Restarted and refreshed the Postfix service
5. Tried sending mail from the terminal, and checked the mail from terminal itself to find the following as a reply :

   ```
   From MAILER-DAEMON  Thu Feb  9 14:53:14 2017
   X-Original-To: Admin@MacBook-Pro.local
   Delivered-To: Admin@MacBook-Pro.local
   Date: Thu,  9 Feb 2017 14:53:14 +0530 (IST)
   From: MAILER-DAEMON@MacBook-Pro.local (Mail Delivery System)
   Subject: Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender
   To: Admin@MacBook-Pro.local
   Auto-Submitted: auto-replied
   MIME-Version: 1.0
   Content-Type: multipart/report; report-type=delivery-status;
           boundary="CD41810841CF.1486632194/MacBook-Pro.local"

   This is a MIME-encapsulated message.

   --CD41810841CF.1486632194/MacBook-Pro.local
   Content-Description: Notification
   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

   This is the mail system at host MacBook-Pro.local.

   I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
   be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

   For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

   If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
   delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                      The mail system

   <varungupta.masters@gmail.com>: host smtp.gmail.com[74.125.200.109] said:
       530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1
       https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError a25sm27067419pgd.26 -
       gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

   --CD41810841CF.1486632194/MacBook-Pro.local
   Content-Description: Delivery report
   Content-Type: message/delivery-status

   Reporting-MTA: dns; MacBook-Pro.local
   X-Postfix-Queue-ID: CD41810841CF
   X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; Admin@MacBook-Pro.local
   Arrival-Date: Thu,  9 Feb 2017 14:53:11 +0530 (IST)

   Final-Recipient: rfc822; varungupta.masters@gmail.com
   Original-Recipient: rfc822;varungupta.masters@gmail.com
   Action: failed
   Status: 5.5.1
   Remote-MTA: dns; smtp.gmail.com
   Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530
       5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError a25sm27067419pgd.26
       - gsmtp

   --CD41810841CF.1486632194/MacBook-Pro.local
   Content-Description: Undelivered Message
   Content-Type: message/rfc822

   Return-Path: <Admin@MacBook-Pro.local>
   Received: by MacBook-Pro.local (Postfix, from userid 501)
           id CD41810841CF; Thu,  9 Feb 2017 14:53:11 +0530 (IST)
   To: varungupta.masters@gmail.com
   Subject: testing
   Message-Id: <20170209092311.CD41810841CF@MacBook-Pro.local>
   Date: Thu,  9 Feb 2017 14:53:11 +0530 (IST)
   From: Admin@MacBook-Pro.local (Admin)

   Thu Feb  9 14:53:11 IST 2017

   --CD41810841CF.1486632194/MacBook-Pro.local--

   acBook-Pro.local--
   ```
6. To work this out I tried allowing the access for less secure apps on the gmail. Turned it on. Still no success.
7. Tried looking into /var/log/mail, I cant see the mail logs. I created a file mail.log in the same directory, it is not registering the logs. I restarted the rsyslog using terminal. Still not working.

Post this I would want to use the mail() function in my PHP scripts and accordingly make changes in the PHP.ini, please if possible suggest the directions for the same as well.

Comment: Did you read https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I did try the same solutions, but let me try them again. Will get back with the response.